# counterexample that $M$ is not finitely generated $R$-module and $M$ has no maximal submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

In the proof of Nakayama Lemma, the following proposition is used:

let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $M$ be a non-zero finitely generated $R$-module. Then $M$ has a maximal submodule.

Is there any counterexample that $M$ is not finitely generated $R$-module and $M$ has no maximal submodule? Thanks.

Comment: $M$ has maximal submodules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb Z_{p^\infty}$ as $\mathbb Z$-module. It is not hard to see that $\mathbb Z_{p^\infty}$ is not finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-module.  Obviously $\mathbb Z_{p^\infty}$ has no maximal subgroup.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$?

Comment: @RenShiquan $\mathbb{Z}_{p^\infty}=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}]/\mathbb{Z}$